# How to replace "\" with "\\" using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am having a string which contains path.

```
$Paths = "Myfolder\Mysubfolder"
```

I need to replace them like "Myfolder\Mysubfolder"

But the `$Paths -replace "\","\\"` fails as regular expression is unable to find and replace "\".

How to replace then?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.Replace()` which does not use regular expressions like this:

```
$Paths = "Myfolder\Mysubfolder"
$Paths.replace('\','\\')
```

To use `-replace` you will need to escape the slash, since it is regex, on the match and *not* the substitution with the exception of `$1` and `$2` ...etc which are used a substitution groups.

```
$Paths -replace '\\','\\'
```

Result from both is:

```
Myfolder\\Mysubfolder
```

Comment: Hey Micky.... please try and make your answers with a little more explanation than "try this" or "does this work"

Comment: The substitution string does use a few (one?) regex metacharacters for specifying substitution groups such as $1 $2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking an = assignment is required?

```
$Paths = "Myfolder\Mysubfolder"
write-Host "debug ..... : $Paths"
$Paths = $Paths.Replace("\","\\")
write-Host "debug ..... : $Paths"
```

This gives:

```
debug ..... : Myfolder\Mysubfolder
debug ..... : Myfolder\\Mysubfolder
```